# code to count columns

Tags: vba, excel

How do I select the last column from second row and move the cursor one cell above.

For eg. if I am at cell A2, how do I make macro to count the number of columns starting from Row 2 and select the cell above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will count the number of columns on row 2 and then select the cell above that one:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim Lastcol As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
    Lastcol = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    'above count the columns on row 2
    ws.Cells(1, Lastcol).Select
End Sub
```

Similarly to Count the number of Rows on a given column:

```
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A
```

Comment: Thank you so much. this is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

to "*select the last column from second row and move the cursor one cell above*", just use

```
Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(-1).Select
```

of course, what above is implicitly referring to currently active worksheet in currently active workbook

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really helpful.